# Problem with integrating Microsoft Login to BlazorWebApp .NET 8.0: Unable to cast "IRemoteAuthenticationService"

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, blazor, asp.net-identity

I try to implement Microsoft Login to my Blazor Web App Project. Im getting an Exception when i try clicking the logout button.
Im getting the Error:

```
Error: System.InvalidCastException: Unable to cast object of type 
'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Server.ServerAuthenticationStateProvider' to type 
'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebAssembly.Authentication.IRemoteAuthenticationService`1[Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebAssembly.Authentication.RemoteAuthenticationState]'.
```

I log in automatically, but can't use the Logout button. If i call "/authentication/login", the same exception will be thrown.
Here is the Main Method:

```c#
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);
    
            // Add services to the container.
            builder.Services.AddRazorComponents()
                .AddInteractiveServerComponents();
    
            //AUTH
    
            builder.Services.AddAuthentication(OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
                            .AddMicrosoftIdentityWebApp(builder.Configuration.GetSection("AzureAd"));
    
            builder.Services.AddControllersWithViews()
                .AddMicrosoftIdentityUI();
    
            builder.Services.AddAuthorization(options =>
            {
                // By default, all incoming requests will be authorized according to the default policy
                options.FallbackPolicy = options.DefaultPolicy;
            });
    
            builder.Services.AddServerSideBlazor()
                .AddMicrosoftIdentityConsentHandler();
    
            builder.Services.AddApiAuthorization();
            builder.Services.AddAuthenticationCore();
    
            builder.Services.AddRazorPages();
            builder.Services.TryAddScoped<AuthenticationStateProvider, AuthStateProvider>();
            builder.Services.AddRemoteAuthentication<RemoteAuthenticationState, RemoteUserAccount, OidcProviderOptions>();
            
            builder.Services.AddScoped<SignOutSessionStateManager>();
    
    
            //SINGELTON
            builder.Services.AddSingleton<DataService>();
            builder.Services.AddSingleton<DataProcessor>();
    
            var app = builder.Build();
    
            // Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
            if (!app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseExceptionHandler("/Error");
                // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
                app.UseHsts();
            }
    
            //AUTH
            app.UseAuthentication();
            app.UseAuthorization();
            app.UseRouting();
    
            app.UseHttpsRedirection();
    
            app.UseStaticFiles();
            app.UseAntiforgery();
    
            app.MapRazorPages();
            app.MapControllers();
            app.MapRazorComponents<App>()
                .AddInteractiveServerRenderMode();
    
            app.Run();
        }
```

I tried to disable prerendering in the App.razor with a new class derivated from InteractiveServerRenderMode,using it in App.razor, but it didnt fixed the problem.

```c#
public class NonPrerenderedServerRenderMode : InteractiveServerRenderMode
{
   public static InteractiveServerRenderMode NonPrerenderedServerMode { get; } = new(false);
}
```

Body of App.razor:

```html
<body>
    <Routes @rendermode=NonPrerenderedServerRenderMode.NonPrerenderedServerMode />
    <script src="_framework/blazor.web.js"></script>
</body>
```

I don't know what the main problem is. Am i missing something? Can somebody help me, to find the Problem and resolve it? Is there another way to integrate Microsoft Login?

Comment: You may want to try Net 7.0.  I've seen some issues with Net 8.0,  See : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/security/?view=aspnetcore-8.0#troubleshoot-errors

Comment: The error indicates you mixed the Authentication component with server side project,try move it  together with related services to your .client project